# Separate FastAPI Server from Celery Workers Server - Directory Structure

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

I am running a FastAPI application on a single server with Celery to do the heavy lifting work. Every request to the FastAPI server kicks of a task on the same server that can run for hours.

Since, currently the API code and celery workers code resides and runs on the same server.
I am launching the API server as:

```
uvicorn app:app.main --port <PORT> --host <HOST>
```

And the workers as:

```
celery -A app.worker worker --loglevel=info
```

The current directory structure is roughly as follows with the tasks defined in `tasks/tasks.py` and discovered by the `worker.py`. The API routes import the specific task function from the `tasks/tasks.py` and call `test_task.delay()` on them.

```
app/
    models/
        __init__.py
        model1.py
        model2.py
    routers/
        __init__.py
        router1.py
        router2.py
    tasks/
        __init__.py
        tasks.py
    main.py
    worker.py
```

But I am expecting high load in the upcoming days. I am looking forward to scaling out with one server only handling the API requests and multiple high end servers running the celery workers, connected to the same broker instance.

**I want the API code to remain as a separate module and the workers to stay as a separate module so that they can be separately deployed but the tasks can be called from the FastAPI application.**

However, I cannot understand how exactly to structure my project files in a way that I don't need to load the FastAPI code on the celery servers, and vice versa, yet keeping the system robust, extensible and production ready.

I am new to this, so kindly excuse me if this is a noob question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't particularly understand why the celery tasks need to import from the api classes, but if you want to remove the dependency on the celery tasks from the api, you should use the [`Celery.send_task`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task) function so that you can call tasks by name instead of needing to import them.

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(broker='some broker url', backend='some backend url')
app.send_task('task_name', kwargs={
    'param1': 'value1',
    'param2': 'value2',
})
```